# Get all fields of a model in Django Shell

Tags: django, django-models, django-shell

Is it possible to output names of all fields of a specific model in Django Shell?
For example, how to get fields from `User` model:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

I know I can get it by accessing `models.py` of the appropriate app but it would be more convenient for me to get information on models of all the apps at the same place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To return a list of **field objects** of the `User` model. Use:

```py
field_names = User._meta.get_fields()
```

To return a list of **field names** for `User` model, Use:

```py
field_names = [f.name for f in User._meta.get_fields()]
```

Comment: It says `AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute '__meta'`

Comment: @SayyorY just use a single underscore. `__` --> `_`

Comment: Nice solution. For your models this also should work (but not in a list): YourModel.__dict__['__doc__']

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can see only the model (without foreign keys fields) by `User._meta.fields`. is there any way to only see the required fields there?

Comment: this can be a new question try asking it as a new one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31988634)